# URL-rewrite module in Apache webserver

Tags: perl, apache, setcookie

I am working on URL-rewrite module of Apache web server. To start with I am not able to configure the same for Windows7. Moving forward, my exact problem statement is -

I have a webapp for which i need to set a cookie everytime a user visits my app. Once the cookie is set I need to read it next time the user visits and modify my URL according to that. I need to set/read the cookie in perl.

I am completely new to perl and Apache Web server.

Comment: What's the question? Show your code!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.

Here are a few ways:

- Plain old [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#HTTP-COOKIES)
- [CGI::Cookie](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Cookie.html)
- If using mod_perl under Apache 1.3.x: Apache::Cookie
- If using mod_perl2 under Apache 2.x: Apache2::Cookie